# Styling the day container background

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

Is there anyway to style the day header container's background with react-native-calendars? I've checked the stylesheet and can't find anyway to change the color apart from changing the color of the entire background which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can add style in `markedDates`

```
<Calendar
  // Date marking style [simple/period/multi-dot/single]. Default = 'simple'
  markingType={'custom'}
  markedDates={{
    '2018-03-28': {
      customStyles: {
        container: {
          backgroundColor: 'green'
        },
        text: {
          color: 'black',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    },
    '2018-03-29': {
      customStyles: {
        container: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          elevation: 2
        },
        text: {
          color: 'blue'
        }
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Apologies @Usman your answer is correct for what I asked, but I meant the day header container, I've edited the question to avoid confusion.